# isKindOfClass Bool if statement logging NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm checking if `toViewController`, which is the 2nd Tab in my tabBar, is of the class `MatchCenterViewController`, but the `else` statement is running instead, which tells me that it's not of that class.

I'm positive that the `UIViewController` in that tab is connected to `MatchCenterViewController`, so what else could cause this `if` statement to not work?

```
NSLog(@"numberOfMatches is 1");

UIViewController *toViewController = [self.tabBarController viewControllers][1];

NSLog(@"toViewController: %@", toViewController);

if ([toViewController isKindOfClass:[MatchCenterViewController class]]) {

    NSLog(@"2nd matchcenter if statement works");
    MatchCenterViewController *matchViewController = (MatchCenterViewController *)toViewController;

    matchViewController.didAddNewItem = YES;

    NSLog(@"alright they're set, time to switch");

}
else {
    NSLog(@"toViewController is not MatchCenterViewController");
}
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: Well you what does the log statement you have right above the check say it is?

Comment: Why are you positive that you have the connections right? Perhaps they aren't.

Comment: What do you see when you run `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[self.tabBarController viewControllers][1] class]);`

Comment: @dan it logs out this: "toViewController: <UINavigationController: 0x7f8610780ff0>"

Comment: @PeterFoti it logs out "UINavigationController"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `NSLog(@"toViewController is of class: %@", NSStringFromClass([toViewController class]);` and see the actual view controller class.

Or if `didAddNewItem` is a property that only **MatchCenterViewController** has, you can try this way:

```
if ([toViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setDidAddNewItem:)]) {
    // this is MatchCenterViewController
} else {
    // this is not MatchCenterViewController
}
```

Comment: That `NSLog` logs out the following: "toViewController is of class: UINavigationController", and the if statement logs out "this is not MatchCenterViewController". Is `[self.tabBarController viewControllers][1]` not the correct way to reference `MatchCenterViewController`?

Comment: Looks like your UITabBarController viewController at index 1 is the UINavigationController that holds MatchCenterViewController. If your hierarchy is `UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> MatchCenterViewController` and MatchCenterViewController is the visible view controller in the second tab, you can try with `UINavigationController *navVC = (UINavigationController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers][1]; MatchCenterViewController *matchCenter = (MatchCenterViewController  *)navVC.topViewController;`